# Get sound rhythm - javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

how to get rhythm using `js` or `jquery`
Following soundcloudes and this image :
what is this name ?

[image]

Comment: you mean audio waves? use some js library such http://justwave.beotiger.com/player.html

Comment: @NicolòCozzani so thanks , yes ! but i dont need player i just need waves

Comment: what you mean? waves are generated from a audio file.

Comment: @NicolòCozzani yes ! but that link is music player . i want to put audio link and get image of waves

Comment: that library can load audio from links

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you right you are looking for a way to generate waveforms. Try this library http://p5js.org/reference/#/p5.FFT